# Search mysql table for term in column, strip term if found

Tags: mysql, sql

In my `wp_posts` table, I have a column named `post_content`. I want to search this column for all instances of `<!--nextpage-->` and strip that if it exists.

So for example, if the following is found in a `post_content` row:

```
hello<!--nextpage-->world lorem
```

Then strip it to:

```
helloworld lorem
```

What SQL query can I run?

Comment: UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<!--nextpage-->', '');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<!--nextpage-->', '')
```

or

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<!--nextpage-->', '')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%<!--nextpage-->%'
```

Comment: You should add a `where` to see if the column has that value.